# Use Chart.js in Drupal page

Tags: javascript

I am new to Drupal. I created a page and I want to embed charts in that page. I am trying to use chart.js and I have question regarding how to import the script of chart.js in the page i created?

is it like this

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

or some other way to do it? I also dont understand how you add javascript code to a drupal page. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define it in either a module, or the libraries.yml file of your theme. Then you need to attach it to the page. See the "CDN / externally hosted libraries" of this doc page:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module

Then you need to attach the library - this is fairly straightforward in mytheme.theme.

Example `mytheme.theme` file:

```
function mytheme_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {
  $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'mytheme/chartjs';
}
```

Comment: is it ok to define in theme.info? like this `scripts[]=js/Chart.js`after downloading the Chart.js file?

Comment: Is this Drupal 7 or 8?

Comment: It is Drupal 7.

Comment: It is a little difficult to understand what u commented. So I tried another way.

Comment: Hello @Kevin , I need to embed a Chart.js within a Drupal 8 page and I would really appreciate if you could elaborate your answer? I can not find the right way to embed a script in CKEditor for example and I guess my external library definition is not right (license, name, url, etc.) Many thanks